# g++ how to do partial link time optimization (-flto)

Tags: g++, lto

I man g++ and read carefully about the lto part. Now I want to know how to do partial link time optimization just like -ipo-c in icpc compiler. For example:

```
g++ -O2 -flto -c a.cpp
g++ -O2 -flto -c b.cpp
```

Now it will generate a.o and b.o which contain GIMPLE (one of GCC's internal representations). I want to combine a.o and b.o to generate a real object c.o file. That means just lto over two cpp file not the whole program. Any idea?

The reason is that I need to combine fortran code and c++ code together, so the final link step is

```
ifort -nofor-main -cxxlib -fexceptions f.o a.o b.o
```

f.o is generated by ifort. Because ifort has no idea what GIMPLE is. So the final link step will fail.

Comment: Can't you just link using `g++ -flto` itself? (I mean, is it a necessity that you link with `ifort`?)

Comment: Yes, I use some of features that just ifort can support. gfortran can not product the correct answer. I have to use ifort to compile all my fortran code.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `g++` to link it.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

GNU Fortran comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Fortran
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING

$ cat a.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" void foo_() { puts("foo"); }

$ cat b.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" void bar_() { puts("bar"); }

$ cat f.f90
program f
        implicit none

        external foo
        external bar

        call foo()
        call bar()
end program

$ g++ -O2 -flto -c a.cpp

$ g++ -O2 -flto -c b.cpp

$ gfortran -O2 -flto -c f.f90

$ g++ -O2 -flto a.o b.o f.o -lgfortran

$ ./a
foo
bar
```

Comment: I have to use ifort to compile all my fortran code and do the final link, because I use some features that only ifort can support.

Comment: @Ken Then I guess you cannot use Link-Time Optimization. LTO requires your compiler to send implementation-specific information to your linker, and it may be different in each implementation. I guess you have to use icc and ifort to use lto.